# Unable to edit "schema" in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

One of the fields I use in BigQuery has changed, I was using Unix/Epoch timestamp and it caused issues on another system integrated into BigQuery.

So I have edited that field on the table to be an ISO 8601 date like "2023-11-17T18:54:37Z"

Unfortunately, the way BigQuery reads the data according to the schema, it returns "2023" and ignores the rest.

I just want to make a change to the schema which currently identifies that field type as "INTEGER" and I want to change to "STRING"

I see absolutely no way to do it - I press "edit schema" and there's no way to change anything and I am the project owner there are no more permissions for me to add.

[SHOWING MY BIGQUERY SCHEMA, AND THE FIELD AND TYPE I AM TRYING TO EDIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwDOG.png)

[WHAT APPEARS WHEN I PRESS 'EDIT SCHEMA' BUTTON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbT1n.jpg)

Comment: Did you try in SQL? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#change_a_columns_data_type

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, unfortunately I had no luck with that, I believe it’s because my tables considered an external table. I just find it wild that there is a button that says, edit, schema, and that button literally has no functionality. I was able to find a workaround but I’m basically stuck if I need to make more extensive changes like adding a column lol